# Any way to use await in Normal function?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to use await inside a normal function?

For Example:

```
function myFunction(v1, v2) {
    let v3 = await some db operation; returns a array
    console.log(v3);
    //do something
};
```

Comment: You should write async flag to function

Comment: In order to execute an async function you need to yield execution at some point. So you either write an async function that can await, or you use promises. Either way you should not block the thread to wait for an async operation since then the operation will never get a chance to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** The "magic" of asynchronous programming – that, in JavaScript, includes the usage of `await` – is that it doesn't block the execution of other code. If you want to use it, you have to adapt your codebase to use `async` functions where it makes sense.

If you really need to wait for asynchronous actions to complete inside normal synchronous functions, you could check whether the library you're using also offers `sync` functions ([`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra#sync) for example does). But *please*, unless there's a really good reason not to, make your code asynchronous.

Answer (score 6):

No, and for a good reason.

Before async functions were introduced: the following was entirely possible:

```
function foo() {
  var await = 42;
  var result = await + 42;
}
```

If they had made it so `await` was available in normal functions, that code would have been retroactively broken, causing what's called a **backwards compatibility break**.

This is also why `yield` is only available within `function*`.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, all async code is called from a normal function *somewhere*, but **no** you can't use the `await` keyword in a non-async function.

Async functions look like promises when inside non-async functions.

```
function myOuterFunction(v1, v2) {
    myFunction(v1, v2)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
}

async function myFunction(v1, v2) {
    let v3 = await some db operation; returns an array
    console.log(v3);
    //do something
};
```

(This example uses the functions `console.log` and `console.error` to handle returned values and exceptions.)